# How to read 'extract' field from JSON data in given URL

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-http

I was trying to to fetch information of a search query using Wikipedia API in Angular. I have created a service and the URL from which I am fetching data is https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=stack_overflow
The results will be shown for user entered query in a text box,In the retrieved data the `pageid` field will be variable so how can I read `extract` field from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Object.keys() method to dynamically retrieve a list of all keys in a object.

For example, calling Object.keys() on result.query.pages on the JSON response from wikipedia would return [6710844], the key of the page you are looking for.

Using this, you can retrieve the 'extract' field.

```
const pageId = Object.keys(result.query.pages)[0];
const pageExtract = result.query.pages[pageId].extract;
```